# Android - library create and use

Tags: java, android, libraries

How can I create library that using in android features? And how can I add this library to my app and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Creating Library, Follow below steps:

Select the `project` from the `Package Explorer` (eclipse) or create a new one and open `Properties` dialog by pressing `Alt+Enter` ( or right click + Properties) and check the `IsLibray` checkbox.

See this link: `http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html`

For adding library project into to your application, Follow below steps:

```
1.File->New->Other
2.Select Android Project
3.Select "Create Project from existing source"
4.Click "Browse..." button and navigate to johannilsson-android-actionbar\actionbar
5.Finish (Now action bar project in your workspace)
6.Right-click on your project -> Properties
7.In Android->Library section click Add
8.select recently added project -> Ok
```

Hope, this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many other questions like this, use the search functionality.

I will give you some hints:

- create a regular android project in eclipse
- go to proprieties
- in Android section check "is Library" checkbox.

Now you can go to other eclipse projects propreties and now you can include your Library project inside others